# Synchronization between SharePoint and own server (not OneDrive)

Tags: server, synchronization

I have a local server (in my network or over VPN) and want to view the folder structure and the files in SharePoint.

Is there a way to read this directly from the server or to synchronize the folders/files?

It is only important for me to display them and then link to the corresponding location on the server.

I would like to do without OneDrive.

Greetings,
Lexinas

Answer (score 1):

1. I am assuming you have important reason to not store the files in SP (they are large like disc images or some other issue)
2. One option for you would be to crawl the content of the file server users then can search for content and use search link to get to that file location.
3. Other option would be for you to use the Link to Document content type. This is special content type that can be used in libraries instead of the document. But there is no out of the box mechanism for you to do that sync, you would have to do it yourself using PowerShell. PowerShell would read the file directory and ensure that there is corresponding item-link to document in the library.